# Example where $E \subset S$, $E \neq \emptyset$, and $P(E) = 0$?

Tags: probability

From what I understand, this situation isn't possible since any non-empty subset of S will have a non-zero probability. What am I missing here?

Comment: What you are missing is correction of the mistaken belief that "this situation isn't possible since any non-empty subset of S will have a non-zero probability."

Comment: But how is that situation even possible if elements in S all have non-zero probability? I do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens in the continuous case, for instance, where the probability of a specific value is null.

Let's consider the example of an arrow hitting a target, which is a disk of radius 1. Imagine it centered in the origin of the Cartesian plane.
Let S be the disk. So P(S)=1, as the arrow have to hit the target somewhere. If you consider for instance E={(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)}, we have that $P(E)=0$, with $E \in S$ and $E \neq \emptyset$, as the probability for the arrow of hitting an exact point is $0$.

At the same time, there are elements in S that have a positive probability. For instance, the disk centered in the origin with radius $1/2$, let's name it S', have a positive probability. So, $S' \in S$, $S' \neq \emptyset$ and $P(S') \neq 0$. Actually, $P(S')=1/4$.

In the continuous case this happens due to a consistency problem. There are infinite points in an interval/disk/region, which we know having probability 1, or at least a finite probability. If we give a positive probability to each of the points, the total sum would diverge, as we would sum infinite fixed positive numbers.

Comment: For the first example, why is $E \in S$ if the points in E are not on the disk?

Comment: You can take any points you want, that was the point of what I've said. Those points are on the boundary of the disk. Everything can be applied also to E={$(1/2,1/2),(1/2,-1/2),(-1/2,1/2),(-1/2,-1/2)$}, for instance. So, no reasons why they are on the boundary, they were just the four easiest points that came to my mind!

Comment: E is a subset of S. S is the unit disk in the xy plane and the four point in E lie on the unit disk. Perhaps this is an easier example: let X be a continuous random variable that is uniformly distributed on [-1,1]. The event {X=0} is non empty, it is a subset of [-1,1], and yet, the P({X=0})=0.